# How I can use this Power Query code inside Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet created in excel office 365. I need to create the same file but inside Excel 2007, because some of the functionality I do in Power Query, I'm not sure how to get that to live.

I use data from DB, so everything should be dynamical. 
There is how this work on the last Excel -

1. ProcedureId - this is a user ID
2. TokenValue - this is question ID
3. HtmlValue - this is answer ID or answer

So, I have 3 columns

[image]

Then I change structure with fx in Power Query to

```
           Question1  Question2  Question3    
User 1     Answer1    Answer2    Answer3
```

I used

```
= Table.Pivot(#"Removed Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"[TokenValue]), "TokenValue", "HtmlValue")
```

[image]

How I can change structure like that with dynamical data in Excel 2007? If VBA, can you help me to translate this line?

[image]

My Power Query code

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("server"),
    chinurseportaldatabase = Source{[Name="name"]}[Data],
    dbo_ProcedureStepsDetails = chinurseportaldatabase{[Schema="dbo",Item="ProcedureStepsDetails"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_ProcedureStepsDetails, each [ProcedureId] > 373),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ProcedureId", "TokenValue", "HtmlValue"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"[TokenValue]), "TokenValue", "HtmlValue")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d) is only available in 2010 and later. I'm not sure what is the best option to do what you want in 2007.

Comment: If users don't need to be able to refresh the data, could you have a "template" in Excel 365 where you can refresh the data before saving as 2007-compatible (minus Power Query) for distribution?

Comment: Although, looking at your code -- I think it may be possible to "translate" completely into SQL (if from a SQL database). Have you tried looking at the "Native Query" in PQ? (Right click steps, select "View Native Query" -- may or may not be possible depending on prior query steps)

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, yes I know. But I have to do this on Excel 2007. So I need to find other option

Comment: @Mistella Thanks, native Query is ‘greyed’ out on last most important step. I will try to use transparent in sql. But this looks complicated.
Any other ideas?